# Possible to run rsync over scp?

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp, ssh-tunneling, sshd

Is it possible to run `rsync` over `scp`.

Reason for involving `scp`: using authentication and encryption.

Reason for not using `rsync` over `ssh`: not giving full shell access to the remote server. Should only be able to write into a designated folder for security.

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` appendix:

```
Match User restricted-user
    ChrootDirectory /home/backup-production
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Comment: You're mixing up scp and sftp. And no, you can't run rsync over sftp, unless you're mounting the remote server via sshfs and treat it as a local filesystem.

Comment: I don't believe you can use scp/sftp explicitly with rsync. As suggested by @UncleBilly you can instead use one of various methods (like `sshfs`) to mount the remote file system locally (using sftp as underlying protocol) and rsync to the local mount point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to run rsync over scp.

No: `scp` is a file copy protocol running over `ssh`.

> Reason for involving scp: using authentication and encryption.

No... that's implemented by the `ssh` transport layer

> Reason for not using rsync over ssh: not giving full shell access to the remote server

That can be implemented within `ssh` by configuring a restricted directory (`chroot`) containing the `rsync` binary, a simple shell (`dash` maybe) and their necessary supporting libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup **rsyncd** on the remote server as a receiver of rsync connections. Its config file fully determines which parts of the filesystem can be written to, or read from, and by which users and machines.
This is what the rsync man page is referring to when it uses `::` in addresses rather than `:`.

It is however over an unencrypted connection (using a password for authentication), though this is not usually a problem for use in internal networks.

But you can also setup an **instant rsyncd** which works over ssh.
You create a user on the server with an entry in their `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file that specifies that on connection the command to run is `rsync --server --daemon --config=file .`, i.e. `rsyncd` with a local config file.